# Passing dotenv to ActiveRecord rake tasks (no Rails)

Tags: ruby, activerecord, task

I'm using ActiveRecords in no-Rails app and I'm trying to use [dotenv](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv) with ActiveRecord rake tasks.

In the documentation of dotenv there is stated that you need to pass it to tasks like this:

```
require 'dotenv/tasks'

task mytask: :dotenv do
   # things that require .env
end
```

But I'm loading my ActiveRecord rake tasks like this in my Rakefile:

```
load 'active_record/railties/databases.rake'
```

How can I pass dotenv to ActiveRecord tasks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should also require dotenv at your Rakefile

```
require 'dotenv/tasks'
load 'active_record/railties/databases.rake'
```

So at the moment of loading your custom tasks, the dotenv will be loaded and ENV will be populated with data.

Comment: Nope, not the case. I'm doing that, as stated in the code example from the dotenv documentation.

Comment: It does not work for you? What problem exactly do you have?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. I get `Database '<%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>' does not exist
` when I run `rake db:drop ENV=test`.

Comment: Then the problem is with your DB config, dotenv works as expected.
It looks like your config is not processed by ERB.

Comment: Aha. I'm loading my config in Rakefile like this: `conf = File.join root, 'config/database.yml'; DatabaseTasks.database_configuration = YAML.load(File.read(conf))` How can Iprocess it by erb here?

Answer (score 0):

Along with `DotEnv` setup, make sure you run:

```
rake db:environment:set
```

to set the environment variables before running any commands that require `ENV`.